# Sort List<> by when item is added?

Tags: c#, linq

I currently have a list of items from an object.  I send the list to another method where it is copied to a csv file. The problem that I have is that the items are being listed on the csv in alphabetical order instead of the order they were added.  I there a way to keep the original order?

```
SampleDatalist.Add(new SampleDataViewModel
{
    PlanID = Convert.ToString(allFields["AdditionalInfo-PlanDetails-planNumber"]),
    SSN = Convert.ToString(allFields["AccountOwnerInfo-ContactInfo-ssn"]),
    EmployeeNumber = "",
    DivisionId = "",
    FirstName = Convert.ToString(allFields["AccountOwnerInfo-ContactInfo-firstName"]),
    MiddleName = "",
    LastName = Convert.ToString(allFields["AccountOwnerInfo-ContactInfo-lastName"]),
    StreetAddress = Convert.ToString(allFields["AccountOwnerInfo-ContactInfo-homeAddress1"]),
    City = Convert.ToString(allFields["AccountOwnerInfo-ContactInfo-homeCity"]),
    State = Convert.ToString(allFields["AccountOwnerInfo-ContactInfo-homeState"]),
    PostalCode = Convert.ToString(allFields["AccountOwnerInfo-ContactInfo-homeZip"]),
    HomePhone = Convert.ToString(allFields["AccountOwnerInfo-ContactInfo-homePhone"]),
    OfficePhone = Convert.ToString(allFields["AccountOwnerInfo-ContactInfo-businessPhone"]),
    Email = Convert.ToString(allFields["AccountOwnerInfo-ContactInfo-email"]),
    DateOfBirth = Convert.ToString(allFields["AccountOwnerInfo-ContactInfo-dob"]),
    DateOfHire = Convert.ToString(allFields["AdditionalInfo-PlanDetails-dateOfHire"]),
    MaritalStatus = Convert.ToString(allFields["AdditionalInfo-PlanDetails-maritalStatus"])
});

WriteCSV(PCSDatalist, @"C:\Users\brand\Documents\New_PPT_" + dt + ".csv");



public void WriteCSV<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, string path)
{
    Type itemType = typeof(T);
    var props = itemType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                        .OrderBy(p => p.Name);

    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(path, true))
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", props.Select(p => p.GetValue(item, null))));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what type is `SampleDatalist`?

Comment: Why not use a [SortedList<>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: are you referring to the items or the columns? bc the columns are being sorted by name.

Comment: Is there a reason you're writing `PCSDatalist` and not `SampleDatalist`?

Comment: I changed is to sampledatalist at the top and forgot to change it in the WriteCSV method.  It was just for display

Comment: List retains the order things were added. So you are sorting it somehow yourself. Simple test: what does the list look like at the start of WriteCSV, what does the debugger show?

Comment: I also note that you add things to one list, then write a completely different one. Waaay more is going on here than you are showing

Comment: It shows it listed in alphabetical order by name.

Comment: Why not just use a queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you show, the items in the list show be written in the order they were added.

However, the *properties* of each item will be written in alphabetical order -- because you specifically ask that they are : `.OrderBy(p => p.Name)`.  If you do not what this, remove that clause, and the properties will be written in the order they are defined in the class.

Comment: Yeah, that was it.  Looked right past that.  Thanks!